# C++11 nested std::conditional

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Whats wrong with this expression?

```
template<class T, class FieldT>
using addRefU = typename std::conditional<
                            // ok when true. When false result has no reference at all
                            false,     
                            typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                            typename std::conditional<
                                true,
                                typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                                typename std::add_lvalue_reference< FieldT >::type
                            >
                        >::type;

int main()
{
        std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<
            addRefU<A, B>
        >::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<
            addRefU<A, B>
        >::value << std::endl;

}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21593805f2c6e634

As a result, it does not have reference at all. Are nested std::conditional's not allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot a `::type` on the nested `conditional`:

```
template<class T, class FieldT>
using addRefU = typename std::conditional<
                            // ok when true. When false result has no reference at all
                            false,     
                            typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                            typename std::conditional<
                                true,
                                typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                                typename std::add_lvalue_reference< FieldT >::type
                            >::type
                        >::type;

int main()
{
        std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<
            addRefU<A, B>
        >::value << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<
            addRefU<A, B>
        >::value << std::endl;

}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bb2d1528115010c)

Comment: And all the indentation in the world can be brought down by the omission of the tiniest `::type`...

Comment: Pure foolishness from my side. It should be compiler error. But it can't (conditional is type too). And they talk that C++ is strongly typed language. Hmm... If there where static_assert in constructor `std::conditional` it would be much safer... At least you'll can't instantiate from it.